# Is it possible to deadlock memory in Lua like this?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, lua, deadlock

Both of these tables have references to each other, but neither are referenced anywhere else outside of the function. Will these tables remain in memory after a call to f() or will they be garbage collected?

```
function f()
     local t1 = {}
     local t2 = {}
     t1[1] = t2
     t2[1] = t1
end

f()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's garbage collection checks for reachability rather than just using reference counting, so circular references will not prevent collection. Here's a modified version of your program to demonstrate this:

```
function f()
     local t1 = setmetatable({}, {__gc = function() print "Collected t1" end})
     local t2 = setmetatable({}, {__gc = function() print "Collected t2" end})
     t1[1] = t2
     t2[1] = t1
end

f()
print "Before collectgarbage()"
collectgarbage()
print "After collectgarbage()"
```

The result I get:

```
Before collectgarbage()
Collected t2
Collected t1
After collectgarbage()
```

Note that the `__gc` metamethod on tables is new to Lua 5.2. If you want to try this demo on older versions of Lua, you'll need to make use of `newproxy` or otherwise acquire a userdata to use instead.

Answer (score 2):

The two tables will be garbage collected.

`t1` and `t2` are local to `f`'s scope. Once they run out of scope `t1[1]` and `t2[1]` no longer exist.

There are no more references to the two tables left so they qualify for garbage collection.